# Проблемы при экспорте apk после добавления Activity в AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Нашел проблему, почему Eclipse экспортил битый apk... Только не могу решить эту проблему.

Если сделать экспорт с таким манифестом:

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ua.tolikol.medievalcraft"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" android:name="ReqOpenGLES2"/>

    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
         <activity android:name="MedievalCraft.main$GameActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

При попытке установить приложение пишет ошибку: "Синтаксическая ошибка при анализе пакета!".

Если сделать экспорт с таким манифестом (Без активити):

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ua.tolikol.medievalcraft"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" android:name="ReqOpenGLES2"/>
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >      
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Приложение устанавливается.

В чем проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Что-то мне не нравится символ "$" в имени активити вашей. Попробуйте его поменять, убрав этот символ.

Comment: Раньше было "MedievalCraft.main.GameActivity", сам активити "GameActivity".
Просто в eclipse висело предупреждение и хотело заменить "MedievalCraft.main.GameActivity" на "MedievalCraft.main$GameActivity", но и это не помогло.

Comment: Так у вас же ещё и имя пакета же не совпадает... В начале вы пишете всё в нижнем регистре (medievalcraft), а в теге активити уже в перемешку с верхним (MedievalCraft). Проверьте ещё раз правильность написания всех пакетов и имён классов.